# Obtener el valor de una variable en una clase desde ajax, de momento el valor que obtengo es undefined

Tags: javascript, html, c#, ajax, singleton

estoy intentando hacer un programa con singleton, lo que se me pidio fue:
"Implementar el patrón de diseño creacional Singleton en backend, con lo que un request ya sea POST o GET, asíncrono o no, el objeto con Singleton sea accesible."
Lo primero que hice fue crear la clase singleton en c#

```
public class Singleton
    {
        private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();
        private Singleton() { }

        public static Singleton Instance
        {
            get { return instance; }

        }

        public string DoSomething()
        {
            string x = "Singleton funciona";
            return x;
        }
    }
```

despues en un aspx.cs le llamo a esta clase:

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static string SingletonCall()
        {
            string x;
            Singleton mySingleton = Singleton.Instance;
            x = mySingleton.DoSomething();
            return x;
        }
```

y en mi html tengo un boton

```
<td><button name="btn-delete" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="Sing()" >Singleton</button></td>
```

y la funcion sing() es esta

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function Sing() {
           
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "About.aspx/SingletonCall",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert((data.ResponseText));
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert($("body").html(data.ResponseText));
                    }
                });
        }
       
    </script>
```

en el succes de la funcion me aparece el alert, solo que el dato que me muestra es un "undefined" alguien tiene idea de que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? No se si estoy mal en el ajax o en el singleton

Comment: en tu funcion SingletonCall estas regresando un string y en el ajax lo tratas como json trata poner solo alert(data)

Comment: me regresa un [Object object]

Comment: Prueba a poner `alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))`

Comment: No me funciona, con el alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)) ni siquiera muestra el alert, no hace nada la pagina, otra cosa de la que me di cuenta es que le puse un break al SingleonCall y nunca entra :/